# How to get Call Log Mobile Number Sim card sloat?

Tags: c#, xamarin

i want to get call log history mobile come in which sim

```
in xamarin form .in android call histroy which number comes in which sim if mobile have two sim sloat
```

Comment: Could you please post more details about your question so that others could help you  better.

Comment: i got the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
        int? SIM1 = null;
        int? SIM2 = null;
        string ICCCodeSIM1 = string.Empty;
        string ICCCodeSIM2 = string.Empty;
```

Android.Content.Context myContext = Android.App.Application.Context;

in call history number give all detail about SubscriptionId,IccId .we have to match that id from simcard detail which we have to get using SubscriptionManager.

```
        SubscriptionManager subscriptionManager1 = (SubscriptionManager)myContext.GetSystemService(Android.Content.Context.TelephonySubscriptionService);
        IList<SubscriptionInfo> subsInfoList = subscriptionManager1.ActiveSubscriptionInfoList;
        foreach (SubscriptionInfo subscriptionInfo in subsInfoList)
        {
            if (SIM1 == null)
            {
                SIM1 = subscriptionInfo.SubscriptionId;
                ICCCodeSIM1 = subscriptionInfo.IccId;
            }
            else if (SIM2 == null)
            {
                SIM2 = subscriptionInfo.SubscriptionId;
                ICCCodeSIM2 = subscriptionInfo.IccId;
            }
        }
```